# Resizing divs and background images to fit page with CSS

Tags: css, html

Say that i want to have a couple of divs on my page with images in the background (like this: http://www.ubudhanginggardens.com/). I know how to set the size of my divs, but the problem is that the background image stays the same if I make the web browser smaller... I want the background image to scale up/down with the web browser.

**CSS**

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
}
#container1 {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    background-image: url(../img/1.png);
}
#container2 {
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
    background-image: url(../img/2.png);
}
```

Comment: assuming CSS3 is an option, you can use [`background-size`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13296529/css-how-to-make-responsive-images

Answer (score 2):

This can be done with pure CSS and does not even require media queries.

To make the images flexible, simply add `max-width:100%` and `height:auto`. Image `max-width:100%` and `height:auto` works in IE7, but not in IE8 (yes, another weird IE bug). To fix this, you need to add `width:auto\9` for IE8.

[Source](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries)

CSS:

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    width: auto\9; /* ie8 */
}
```

And if you want to enforce a fixed max width of the image, just place it inside a container, for example:

```
<div style="max-width:500px;">
    <img src="..." />
</div>
```

[jsFiddle example here](http://jsfiddle.net/cTxYc/). No javascript required. Works in latest versions of Chrome, Firefox and IE (which is all I've tested).

Comment: The question is about scaling background images, not foreground images.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to have your image scale with your browser, set the width to a percent instead of defining it as a number of pixels.

So if you wanted the image to always cover half of a div:

```
<div class="my_div">
    <img src="http://example.com"></img>
</div>
<style>
    .my_div .image {
        width:50%;
    }
</style>
```

As you change your browser window size, the size of the image will change. You might want to take a look at Responsive CSS Frameworks, such as [Twitter's Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap), which can help you achieve exactly this behavior.

Comment: class `my_div` is in the markup but not class `image` which you've defined in your CSS. Did you intend `.my_div img` ?

Comment: The question is about scaling background images, not foreground images.