# Image size on different device width for mobile site

Tags: html, jquery-mobile, mobile

How does we take care of image sizes on different devices for mobile site.

Comment: Use, for example, relative width property in CSS (e.g. width:30%;)

Comment: Some people do different style sheets, others make there entire site responsive.

Answer (score 1):

Responsive design is one of the answers. You can read more about that concept here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Responsive_web_design

Here is a very good post about making images responsive http://css-tricks.com/which-responsive-images-solution-should-you-use/

and, of course, take a look around this site ;) [CSS - how to make responsive images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13296529/css-how-to-make-responsive-images)

Answer (score 0):

I guess it depends on what you are doing, but one of doing it is to put the image in a container and then make it a percent of that width.

For example:

```
<div id="myContainer">
<img id="myImage" src="myImage.jpg"> 
<div>
```

Then your css could be:

```
#myImage { width: 50%; }
```

Then it would always be 50% of the width of myContainer, which, in responsive design, might be 100% of your viewport with a max-width set for desktop browsers, or, it could be set by a CSS media query.

As far as the heights go, modern device browsers will set it proportionally to the width that is determined.