# Android: How to compress an image in Webview o save data?

Tags: android, android-webview, android-image

I've used the below code to make the image fit the WebView.

```
String webViewSoruce = "<img src= "http://mywebsite.com/img.jpeg">
String head = "<head><style>img{max-width: 100%; width:auto; height: auto;}</style></head>";
String mWebViewSource= "<html>" + head + "<body>" + webViewSoruce + "</body></html>";
```

The content is loading correctly as expected.
However, the images in the source links are huge and consume lot of data. Also, it takes long time to load in slow internet connection.

How can I compress/reduce the size of images in the WebView?

- to save the data and also helpful for slower connection

Comment: Don't download a big image? See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13296529/css-how-to-make-responsive-images

Comment: Thank you..  @MorrisonChang